# How to remove the tags from appearing in exposed filter textfield

Tags: views, 8

I've a view in Drupal 8, in which I've an ajax auto complete field, which contains tags. I've not checked Unformatted dropdown, and Unformatted suggestion. In this case, I'm getting the autocomplete dropdown as plain text, when I select any one of it, it is showing tags in the field.

Can I remove it?? I don't want my use to see the tags in the search field once they select it

Comment: In other words, don't show tags that have been already selected in the auto complete, so they cannot write the same tag twice?

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes, exactly